# How do I give a variable storage size to an out of scope array?

Tags: c

I have an array and a variable that will hold its size. This array is global (outside of main). The thing is that I don't know the size so I would have to declare it like this (psuedo-code):

```
int a[]; // don't know the size yet (outside main)

int size = [user input] // this is inside main
```

The size variable is inside main. This is where the problem arises:

How would I give the size to the array *after* user input? My array needs to be global, so I'm having trouble figuring this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C you cannot have a variable length array with file-scope.

What you can do is to use a file-scope pointer and allocate memory with `malloc`.

```
#include <stdlib.h> 

int *a;  // outside main

int main(void)
{
    a = malloc(user_input * sizeof *a);  // this is inside main 

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Okay, great example; I get it now!

Comment: @MemyselfandI - Once you have it, you can access it like an array `a[0] = 5;`, but since it's dynamic don't forget to free it when you're done.

Comment: @ouah I wrote it before you update your answer . I will remove it

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a dynamically allocated array.

```
int *a;  /* sure you need it global? */
```

Inside a function (main?) initialize it with:

`a= malloc(sizeof(int)*usersize);`

and read about [C memory management](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a pointer and pointing to an array which will be allocated dynamically

```
int *a;
```

and then in the mai n when you get the size you can allocate memory for your array and the a pointer pointing on it:

```
a = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: `int *a;` is not a pointer to array, it's a pointer to `int`.